# How does one check whether a value inside an input is a valid email?

Tags: opus-ui

I'd like to check for validation on a email input, when a user inserts there email but does not include certain characters included in a email, It should give an error noting that the email address you inserted is not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with a regular expression (please note that this is in itself a complex topic if you want to be 100% compliant: [See this relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression))

```
{
    "type": "containerSimple",
    "wgts": [
        {
            "id": "i1",
            "type": "input",
            "prps": {
                "regex": "^$|^[^\\s@]+@[^\\s@]+\\.[^\\s@]+$",
                "errorOverrides": {
                    "regex": "Email Address is invalid."
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "label",
            "prps": {
                "flows": [
                    {
                        "from": "i1",
                        "fromKey": "error",
                        "toKey": "cpt"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```